# How a Jonin ensured that they can pass their genins as there should be only 9 graduates?

Tags: naruto

Kakashi told the group that there is 66 per cent failure rate, that means only 9 of the 27 academy graduates can pass. And it's in the hand of jonin who is instructing a group of 3, whether he/she want to pass his group or not. So what if all jonin want to pass their group, then how the failure rate would be maintained in that case?

[image: From Naruto SQ EP4 @7:04]

Comment: Is that an absolute limit, or an observation?  Does it actually mean that only nine can pass, or that (on average) of a class of 27, nine will pass?

Comment: The latter one, of a class of 27, nine will pass.

Comment: Which episode/chapter is the from? I don't read the manga, but I don't recall this scene every showing in the anime

Comment: Naruto season 1 episode 4 at 7:04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rate is a measurement, not a rule. If the 27 students had passed, they'd all become genin. The 66% rate is just the statistics considering the rate of graduation up to that point.